# Change the content of a record field from an XML file

Tags: xml-serialization, odoo

In OpenERP XML fields are used to load module data.
The `<record>` tag is used for this.
When reinstalling the module, the records are rewritten with the current data in the XML file.

But is there a way to change just one of the record fields without rewriting all the others?

For instance, in `addons/project_issue/project_issue_view.xml` we have this action definition:

```
    <record id="project_issue_categ_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Issue Categories</field>
        <field name="res_model">crm.case.categ</field>
        <field name="view_type">form</field>
        <field name="view_id" ref="crm.crm_case_categ_tree-view"/>
        <field name="domain">[('object_id.model', '=', 'project.issue')]</field>
        <field name="context" eval="{'object_id': ref('model_project_issue')}"/>
    </record>
```

Is it possible to change just the `name` field in an XML file of a custom module?

I already tried :

```
    <record id="project_issue.project_issue_categ_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Issue Categorization</field>
    </record>
```

and

```
    <update id="project_issue.project_issue_categ_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
        <field name="name">Issue Categorization</field>
    </update>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
<record id="project_issue.project_issue_categ_action" model="ir.actions.act_window">
    <field name="name">Issue Categorization</field>
</record>
```

Your given code will change the name but won't affect menu name. You can see your given action name in form and tree view. 
To change menu name, you have to override menu only not action.

For example:

```
<record id="project_issue.menu_project_issue_category_act" model="ir.ui.menu">
    <field name="name">Issue Categorization</field>
</record>
```

You can even refer [Apply groups on already created menus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13450393/apply-groups-on-already-created-menu)

Comment: The point made about updating `ir.ui.menu` instead of `ir.actions.act_window` is right, but my question is more generic (probably the example I chose was unfortunate). I'm afraid your code sample suffers from the same problem I'm experiencing: `name`is changed, but y«the other record's field content is wiped.